# Every subset of $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ it is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ with the product topology. Is it true that every subset of $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ is it compact if and only if it is closed and bounded?

I think it's worth it. Because the one way implication is fulfilled. Because there is a theorem that tells you that every compact subset of a metric space is generally closed and bounded. And $ \Bbb R ^ {\omega} $ is metricizable with the following metric $$D(x,y)=\sup\{\bar{d}(x_i,y_i)/i: i\in\mathbb N\} $$ where $\bar{d}$ is the bounded metric standard in $\Bbb R$.

It would be necessary to try the reciprocal to conclude my exercise. Someone help me with that part, I have no idea to do it.

Comment: How is your $D(x,y)$ a metric? I'm not sure I understand the definition but it seems to be a set, not a real number. Anyway, I believe the answer to your question is negative, for any compatible metric. Because any metric space is the union of countably many bounded closed sets, but $\mathbb R^\omega$ is not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: I was wrong. I will correct. By the way, is there no other way to test it? Because in the topics that I'm seeing I still don't know what it is $\sigma$-compact. @bof

Comment: In your metric $D$ every set is bounded. The whole space is therfore closed and bounded, but not compact.

Comment: How could you define a subset that is bounded and closed but is not compact with the product toplogy in $ \Bbb R ^ {\omega} $. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I already did that. My set is $\mathbb R^{\omega}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand. What you did was take the "subset" $ \Bbb R ^ {\omega} $ which is closed and bounded, but $ \Bbb R ^ {\omega} $ is not compact. Which is the perfect counterexample. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **any** metric which is compatible with the product topology on $\mathbb R^\omega$. Let $B_n$ be the closed ball of radius $n$ centered at the origin. The sets $B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots$ are bounded closed sets, and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n=\mathbb R^\omega$. Assume for a contradiction that all of the sets $B_n$ are compact. Let $\pi_n:\mathbb R^\omega\to\mathbb R$ be the projection map onto the $n^\text{th}$ coordinate. Let $b_n=\max\{\pi_n(x):x\in B_n\}$, which exists since $\pi_n$ is a continuous function and $B_n$ is a nonempty compact set. Define a point $x\in\mathbb R^\omega$ so that $\pi_n(x)=b_n+1$ for every $n$. Then $x\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it :).